# Per-pixel contrast control using fixed pipeline

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I'm using fixed-pipeline rendering, and would like to control the contrast of my images (i.e., difference from background) in a per-pixel manner. In other words, if C is R/G/B, I'd like to get

C = A*Cs + (1 - A)*C0

where C0 is the background color, and A can vary from pixel to pixel. If the background is black (C0 = 0), I know how to do this: first set the alpha in the framebuffer to what I want on a per-pixel basis, then

`glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ZERO)`

If the background isn't black, then you can set the alpha, clear the color to background, and do

`glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA)`

This works only if none of the objects you draw overlap; in case of overlap, the framebuffer value is no longer the background color, and therefore you no longer get C = A*Cs + (1 - A)*C0.

Is there some obvious way to do this that I'm missing? Maybe I shouldn't use alpha blending but something else?

Comment: Render to a texture, clear the screen with the background, render the texture on top of that. Why are you limiting yourself to the fixed-function pipeline? Is it because you have not learned how to use shaders?

Comment: how about [texture combine units](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Combiners)? IIRC it could be used to combine 2 textures with the blending like rules  so you can always use background texture as one of the source textures... but I haven't use that stuff for 10+ years so I might be remembering it wrong